# How can we load two dataframe columns into a popup in folium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, folium

I have a dataset that looks like this.

```
Procedure   Code_Type   Code    NDC Rev_Code    Procedure_Description   Payer   Plan(s) IP_Price    OP_Price    Discounted_Cash_Price   IP_Negotiated_Charge    OP_Negotiated_Charge    PB_Negotiated_Charge    De-Identified_Minimum_Negotiated_Charge_(IP)    De-Identified_Maximum_Negotiated_Charge_(IP)    De-Identified_Minimum_Negotiated_Charge_(OP)    De-Identified_Maximum_Negotiated_Charge_(OP)    ID  hospital_name   lat lon
7509657101  EAP 96571           BRONCHOSCOPY WITH PHOTODYNAMIC THERAPY EACH ADDITIONAL 15 MINUTES   1199 NATIONAL BENEFIT FUND [5140]   1199SEIU BENEFIT FUND [514001]  1,073.73    1,073.73    429.49      32              29.82   697.92  36  Atlanta Center for Medical Research, Atlanta, GA, USA   33.739876   -84.512581
7710001A01  EAP CPTÂ® 0001A     0771 - PREVENTIVE CARE SERVICES - VACCINE ADMINISTRATION    IMM ADMN SARSCOV2 30MCG/0.3ML DIL RECON 1ST DOSE    1199 NATIONAL BENEFIT FUND [5140]   1199SEIU BENEFIT FUND [514001]  100 100 0       40              16.94   80  41  Synergy Spinecare & Rehabilitation Medicine, Teaneck, NJ, USA   40.873272   -74.012093
7710001A01  EAP CPTÂ® 0001A     0771 - PREVENTIVE CARE SERVICES - VACCINE ADMINISTRATION    IMM ADMN SARSCOV2 30MCG/0.3ML DIL RECON 1ST DOSE    AETNA COMM [5020]   MERITAIN HEALTH [502006]    42.35   42.35   0       29.65               16.94   80  9   Massachusetts General Hospital, Boston, MS, USA 42.3624 -71.069206
7710002A01  EAP CPTÂ® 0002A     0771 - PREVENTIVE CARE SERVICES - VACCINE ADMINISTRATION    IMM ADMN SARSCOV2 30MCG/0.3ML DIL RECON 2ND DOSE    1199 NATIONAL BENEFIT FUND [5140]   1199SEIU BENEFIT FUND [514001]  100 100 0       40              20  80  26  Forest Hills Medical Services, Queens, NYC, NY, USA 40.73431    -73.84951
7710002A01  EAP CPTÂ® 0002A     0771 - PREVENTIVE CARE SERVICES - VACCINE ADMINISTRATION    IMM ADMN SARSCOV2 30MCG/0.3ML DIL RECON 2ND DOSE    AETNA COMM [5020]   MERITAIN HEALTH [502006]    70.73   70.73   0       49.51               20  80  21  Park Avenue Smiles, Yonkers, NYC, NY, USA   40.945873   -73.890671
7710011A01  EAP CPTÂ® 0011A     0771 - PREVENTIVE CARE SERVICES - VACCINE ADMINISTRATION    IMM ADMN SARSCOV2 100 MCG/0.5 ML 1ST DOSE   1199 NATIONAL BENEFIT FUND [5140]   1199SEIU BENEFIT FUND [514001]  100 100 0       40              16.94   80  17  New York’s Presbyterian Lower Manhattan Hospital, NYC, NY, USA  40.710255   -74.005058
7710011A01  EAP CPTÂ® 0011A     0771 - PREVENTIVE CARE SERVICES - VACCINE ADMINISTRATION    IMM ADMN SARSCOV2 100 MCG/0.5 ML 1ST DOSE   AETNA COMM [5020]   MERITAIN HEALTH [502006]    42.35   42.35   0       29.65               16.94   80  50  Baptist East Hospital, Memphis, TN, USA 35.2005 -89.788216
7710012A01  EAP CPTÂ® 0012A     0771 - PREVENTIVE CARE SERVICES - VACCINE ADMINISTRATION    IMM ADMN SARSCOV2 100 MCG/0.5 ML 2ND DOSE   1199 NATIONAL BENEFIT FUND [5140]   1199SEIU BENEFIT FUND [514001]  100 100 0       40              20  80  29  Brooklyn Abortion Clinic, Brooklyn, NY, New York, USA   40.689743   -73.982368
7710012A01  EAP CPTÂ® 0012A     0771 - PREVENTIVE CARE SERVICES - VACCINE ADMINISTRATION    IMM ADMN SARSCOV2 100 MCG/0.5 ML 2ND DOSE   AETNA COMM [5020]   MERITAIN HEALTH [502006]    70.73   70.73   0       49.51               20  80  50  Baptist East Hospital, Memphis, TN, USA 35.2005 -89.788216
3100015M01  EAP CPTÂ® 0015M     0310 - LABORATORY PATHOLOGICAL - GENERAL CLASSIFICATION ADRENAL CORTICAL TUMOR, BIOCHEMICAL ASSAY OF 25 STEROID MARKERS, UTILIZING  1199 NATIONAL BENEFIT FUND [5140]   1199SEIU BENEFIT FUND [514001]  1   1   0       0.85                0.01    0.85    34  UC Physicians Medical Arts Building, Cincinnati, Ohio, USA  39.136597   -84.505058
```

Now, I am trying to create a foilum map that shows lat and lon, plus two columns in my data frame.

Here is my code.

```
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

m = folium.Map(location=[40.74, -73.98], zoom_start=10)


for i in range(0,len(df_final)):
    folium.Marker([df_final['lat'].iloc[i],df_final['lon'].iloc[i]],
            popup=df_final[['hospital_name','Discounted_Cash_Price']]).add_to(m)
        
m
```

When I run it, I get this.

[image]

It seems like there is lots and lots of superfluous info packed  here. I was expecting one sting for hospital_name and one float for Discounted_Cash_Price, but I am getting lots of lots of extra things. Maybe the data set is not being parse correctly. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Your coordinates are indexed(ie iloc) but your popup is not

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work.

```
m = folium.Map(location=[40.74, -73.98], zoom_start=10)


for i in range(0,len(df_final)):
    folium.Marker([df_final['lat'].iloc[i],df_final['lon'].iloc[i]],
            popup = "Hospital: " + str(df_final.hospital_name[i]) + '<br>' +
                    "Price: " + str(df_final.Discounted_Cash_Price[i])).add_to(m)
       
m
```

[image]